# unselect the value in a dropdown when unckeck the checkbox using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Hi folks I am working on ckeckbox with dropdown in a knockoutjs with durandaljs as a router.The values of dropdown getting dynamically from another table.My problem is even When i uncheck the checkbox i am getting the value from dropdown My code is as follows.Whe i unckeck the checkbox the dropdown value should be null.

```
var projectToAdd = {
     project_TestingCheck: ko.observable(false),
     project_DevelopmentCheck: ko.observable(false),
}
```

My Html is like dis

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checked: projectToAdd.project_TestingCheck" />
         Testing                                             
    </label>
    &nbsp;                                        
        <select id="select1" data-bind="options: costCodeDropdown, optionsValue:'Id', optionsText:'Name', optionsCaption: 'Select...', value:projectToAdd.project_TestingCheck()?projectToAdd.project_Testing : "", enable:projectToAdd.project_TestingCheck">               
        </select>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the `value` binding you need to use a function that will be evaluated each time `projectToAdd.project_TestingCheck()` changes:

```
value: function() { return projectToAdd.project_TestingCheck() ? projectToAdd.project_Testing : ""; }
```

But it would be better to move this function in your view model to have a simpler binding:

View model:

```
var projectToAdd = {
     project_TestingCheck: ko.observable(false),
     project_DevelopmentCheck: ko.observable(false),
     project_TestingWithCheck: function() {
         return this.project_TestingCheck() ? this.project_Testing : ""; 
     }
}
```

Binding: `value: projectToAdd.project_TestingWithCheck`